# Firefox сильно тормозит при проигрывании видео в 60fps под Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, браузер

Проблема актуальна в разных дистрибутивах (пробовал на Manjaro и Ubuntu): при проигрывании видео на Youtube в 60 fps нагрузка на все ядра процессора возрастает до предела. Видеокарта по всей видимости не используется.

Видеокарта у меня довольно старая, но её мощности предостаточно для проигрывания видео (GTX465). Проприетарный драйвер Nvidia установлен.

В Хромиуме же процессор отдыхает и никаких тормозов нет, но меня не устраивает Хромиум из за его прожорливости к оперативной памяти и медленного запуска.

Пробовал включать/выключать `media.hardware-video-decoding.force-enabled` в `about:config`, это ничего не меняет. Пробовал запускать видео в режиме инкогнито с отключенными расширениями,также безрезультатно.